# How do I keep gdal.ReprojectImage from ignoring zeroes?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, map-projections

I'm using gdal.ReprojectImage to regrid a GRIB raster from Lambert conformal to longitude/latitude coordinates, and some parts of the lon/lat domain (the corners, more or less) fall outside the input grid. I want the result to have no-data values in those out-of-bounds areas. Here is what the result should look like, with white indicating no data areas and light pink indicating a value of zero:

[HRRR APCP 2019-01-22 12Z f03 (contourf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlP1P.png)

That is the correct result, but it is happening internally in the contourf function, which doesn't work for me. I'm not just trying to draw a picture. I need the data. Note that in this case the input dataset does not have any no-data values.

If I define a no-data value but do not fill the raster band with it explicitly before calling ReprojectImage, both zero values and out-of-bounds areas are set to zero in the result:

Code:
    `dest_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(ndv)
    gdal.ReprojectImage(source_ds,
                        dest_ds,
                        source_ds.GetProjection(),
                        dest_ds.GetProjection(),
                        gdalconst.GRA_Bilinear)`

[HRRR APCP 2019-01-22 12Z f03 (no ndv pre-fill)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2PMj.png)

If I explicitly fill the band with no-data values by adding

Code:`dest_ds.GetRasterBand(1).Fill(ndv)`

before the call to gdal.ReprojectImage, *all the zeroes* in the original grid are deprojecting to no-data values.

[HRRR APCP 2019-01-22 12Z f03 (ndv pre-fill)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJGB.png)

It looks as if ReprojectImage, when it encounters an interpolation neighborhood of all zeroes, leaves those areas of the output grid to their default value. It's like there's some kind of a continue statement in the source code creating a problem here.

I suppose I could create a mask, reproject that, and apply the result to the reprojected data, but is there a better solution I'm missing?

Using python3-gdal 2.2.3 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04.

Comment: Turns out that adding the explicit "Fill" did give the correct result from ReprojectImage, and the contourf function is responsible for the odd behavior. If the output image has a significant number of values below the lowest contour level--for example a large negative no-data value--then values of that lowest contour level (0.0 for my plots) are displayed as white (this does not occur if there are only a few values lower than 0.0). However, if the lowest contour level is set to e.g. -1.0e-6, then zeroes will be included in the first color. Not sure why.